# Show original shortcut in MacOS 10.14

Tags: finder, shortcut, symlink

I often make symbolic links of folders. I recently had to change my laptop and move from Sierra to Mojave.
In the old OS I used to type Cmd + R to go to the original folder. This seems to no longer work. The official apple website still has Cmd + R as the shortcut (https://support.apple.com/el-gr/HT201236).

Comment: Check if there's a menu item for the same action. If it exists, it'll likely list the shortcut right there. An easy way to find a menu item, if you can sort of guess what the name would be, is to open the `Help` menu and type the name right there. Can't check it myself right now.

Comment: Thanks, I did not think about that. Seems like it's now cmd + option + ctrl + a                               
Not the easiest shortcut to type...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change it to `Cmd+R`. Go to `System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts (tab) > App Shortcuts (left sidebar)` click the plus and in the window: `Application: Finder`, `Menu title: Show Original` Just the menu item written exactly as it is in the menu, `Shortcut: Cmd+R`.

> When you change the shortcut, it'll show up in the menu item.